# Control Theory Textbook

Tags: control-theory

I'm looking for a good textbook or series of lecture notes for learning about sampled data control theory. I'm a relative beginner in this area, so I'm looking for a gentle introduction. I'm particularly trying to learn how to formally reason about the safety of sampled data control systems, e.g. a digital controller that keeps the height of a system below a certain value. A textbook that touches on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book I used also uses Matlab and shows examples on how to implement control in Matlab.

[Automatic Control Systems by Goinaraghi Kuo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470048964)

Another book I used was

[Feedback Control of Dynamical Systems by Franklin, Powell, and Emami-Naeini](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133496597)

This book also uses Matlab as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are many standard textbooks, with similar technical content. A favorite, especially for the coverage of the engineering intuition as well as the technical tools, is Karl Åström's:

[http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Controlled-Systems-Theory-Design-Edition/dp/0133148998](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133148998)

Comment: Astrom is a great author to follow. Also his recent book with Murray is very broad but gives a good overview.